# use of しゃれ vs 冗談

Tags: words, nuances

I'm studding for the JLPT and found a phrase よくしゃれを言う人。After I looked up the definition of しゃれ I assumed the phrase meant "jokester". But what is the difference between しゃれ　and 冗談？

I kind of got the idea that しゃれ is more of a witty comment. Is that right? I would also assume you can't say "しゃれだったよ！" like "冗談だった！" for "just kidding!" or "I was just joking"

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59759/1628

Comment: 「よくしゃれを言う人」という場合の「しゃれ」は、pun、語呂合わせのことじゃないですかね。。　冗談じゃない真面目なシャレもありますよね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [all-knowing Chiebukuro](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1419674484), apparently `洒落{しゃれ}` is used for smart/witty comments or jokes, usually with the intention to make someone laugh, while `冗談{じょうだん}` could refer to things like teasing, fooling around or making fun of someone. So it seems "しゃれだったよ！" is not a correct usage for "just kidding!".

Then there is `おしゃれ` used to refer to fashionable/trendy/stylish/elegant people or things.